# How to implement a track ball as the line series for column, ohlc and candlestick in highstock?

Tags: highcharts

We want to show the same trackball for the column, ohlc and candlestick series style as line series in highstock(show a circle symbol track ball).

Is there suggestions or ways that we can follow to implement this within highstock?

And we meet another issue, it when we change the chart style from OHLC to line, by updating the data and style of the series, it will cause the chart to show empty, is there way to resovle this issue?

Thansk

Comment: Could you show example (mockup) of that track ball? And regarding error - recreate issue on jsFiddle, please.

Comment: The issue for update the chart style, I find the reason. It is becasue I sent a chart style for the basic series when there is no data on the chart.

Comment: And how to implement the track ball is the biggest issue I have. http://jsfiddle.net/YevHj/1/  Above is a example, it show a line , a candlestick and a volume in the chart. When mouse move there is a trackball for the line, but for the volume and candlestick there is no trakball, and we want to show the same track ball for the volume and candlestick. Is there any way that we can used to implemented this?

Comment: The style change issue is fixed, how to implemet the trackball?

Comment: What you mean by trackball, could you attach mockup/ image with your concetp (as Pawel mentioned)